# Ignoring a word/path with regex

Tags: regex-negation

I've be trying to do some redirects from a blog, to another. The paths would be like this:

> From:  domain/blog/posts
>
> to: diferentDomain/blog/posts

So i came with this solution:

```
^/blog/(.*)
```

The thing is, i don't want a redirect when the origin URL has this path:

> domain/blog/**"wp-admin"**

So i wrote something like this:

```
^/blog/(?!wp-admin)(.*)
```

But is not working at all... Does somebody knows what is happening?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to escape the forward slashes, like so:

`^\/blog\/(?!wp-admin)(.*)`

Here's your regex in a playground which highlights the error:

https://regex101.com/r/mXs4S2/1

Comment: Hey @ptim, thanks for the answer. I tried with this regex you sent me, but unfortunately it didn't work :(

I'm using this regex with a Wordpress plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/.
I don't know if this issue is related to the plugin, so i'm doing some tests in .htaccess file.

Comment: Aha! Gotcha - don't think that redirection plugin requires escaping forward slashes (but it's been a while...). Consider searching / asking at https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=redirection+plugin (and I'm sure you've checked the docs: https://redirection.me/, though they're sparse). Suggest removing the leading caret `^` - the examples don't show it 